# How can I find an always updated list of repository mirrors?

Tags: official-repositories, mirrors

How can I find an always updated list of repository mirrors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an extensive list of repository mirrors, including how up-to-date they are, [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). If you click on a mirror it will give you the URL to use in your software sources (or source.list).

For CD image mirrors, see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors).