# How to find the list of apt-get mirrors, and specify one to use?

Tags: apt

The default mirror for my `apt-get` is always returning Hash Sum mismatch.

How do I find the list of mirrors and specify one? I am not concerned about speed. I just want to install updates reliably.

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9408/how-can-i-find-an-always-updated-list-of-repository-mirrors