# can anyone help me with this apt update issue in ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: apt, permissions, updates

[image from software update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWZWO.png)

```
Ign:1 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic InRelease                                       
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                
Ign:3 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease         
Ign:4 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease       
Ign:5 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-security InRelease        
Err:6 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 103.163.246.243 443]
Err:7 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 103.163.246.243 443]
Err:8 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 103.163.246.243 443]
Err:9 https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 103.163.246.243 443]
Get:10 https://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease [35.1 kB]
Err:10 https://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A87015F3DA22D980
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu mantic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: `404  Not Found` suggests a network issue, not an apt issue. Did you try opening that URL in a browser?

Comment: Try a different mirror.

Comment: Same 404 Not Found .  I actually ussed  ```apt autoremove ```  .  The issue seem to occurred after that. Btw mirror limda is one of my local surver.  Same issue occors when i use main surver.

Answer (score 1):

About the volian key not available error:

`Err:10 https://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease` 
`The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A87015F3DA22D980`

The key appears to be available on https://deb.volian.org/volian/ (at https://deb.volian.org/volian/scar.key ) and also on https://keys.openpgp.org/search?q=A87015F3DA22D980

Just downloading the keyfile so `apt` can find it should fix that error. `apt-key` used to be for managing apt keys, but it's been deprecated... it's man page's Depricated section recommends this:

> Recommended: Instead of placing keys into the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d directory, you can
> place them anywhere on your filesystem by using the Signed-By option in your sources.list
> and pointing to the filename of the key. See sources.list(5) for details. Since APT 2.4,
> /etc/apt/keyrings is provided as the recommended location for keys not managed by
> packages.

So wherever you put the key, edit it's sources.list entry to match it's location.

Or instead of doing it manually, just follow [Volian's help page here](https://volian.org/pyshell/sections/initial_setup.html) that has these instructions for using their Volian repo:

```
echo "deb http://deb.volian.org/volian/ scar main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/volian-archive-scar-unstable.list
wget -qO - https://deb.volian.org/volian/scar.key | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/volian-archive-scar-unstable.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pyshell
```

---

Two possible issues about the mirror.limda.net errors:

1. From [this Q about finding an updated list of repository mirrors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9408/how-can-i-find-an-always-updated-list-of-repository-mirrors) and checking https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors I don't see mirror.limda.net mentioned anywhere (even searching the html source).
2. Browsing to https://mirror.limda.net/Ubuntu doesn't seem to return anything.

   But going to https://mirror.limda.net/ shows that https://mirror.limda.net/ubuntu-archive/ is a valid link, so that link might possibly work?

I would suggest picking a different official mirror from the link in part 1. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: the issue is mainly about this link   `Err:5 https://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A87015F3DA22D980`  everything else seems ok now.

Comment: Ah, ok. The key looks like it's on the volian.org site, and also in keys.openpgp.org, I'll edit the answer